# Function to automate image loading using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In one of my projects, I successfully used the following code to render a png image in an html5 canvas using JavaScript.

```
var sizeIcon = new Image();
sizeIcon.draw = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(sizeIcon, tooltip.x + 10, tooltip.y + 10);
};

sizeIcon.onload = sizeIcon.draw;
sizeIcon.src = "./images/icons/ruler.png";
tooltip.icons.push(sizeIcon);
```

Since I have multiple icons to load, I implemented the following function:

```
var imageLoader = function(x, y, src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.draw = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
    };

    image.onload = image.draw;
    image.src = src;
    tooltip.icons.push(image);
};

imageLoader(tooltip.x + 10, tooltip.y + 10, "./images/icons/ruler.png");
```

With tooltip.icons being a globally accessible array.
This function does nothing (and does not produce any error nor warnings in the console). I also tried filling the tooltip.icons array directly using something like `tooltip.icons[n] = new Image();` without success (where `n = tooltip.icons.length`). There is probably a part of the JavaScript scope that I don't understand.

Comment: Where is `ctx` defined?

Comment: This probably doesn’t have anything to do with `tooltip.icons`, since there’s no error. Are you using the same image each time? If the image is cached, I don’t think `onload` is fired.

Comment: ctx is the canvas drawing context which is a global obtained using ``ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");`` on the canvas DOM element.
And no the images are different. Repeating the large block works, but I wanted to use the function to avoid repeating myself.

Comment: As @minitech suggested, it could be a problem of caching. Could you try using this line? `image.src = src + "?_" + (+new Date());

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work. When I change the code back to the first version (the "manual" way), it works so I don't know if this is a caching issue. I was wondering if maybe it was related to garbage collection?

Comment: Can you setup a simple fiddle?

Comment: @legaultmarc: No, there is absolutely nothing in JavaScript related to garbage collection.

Comment: Well it works on the Fiddle... Thank you for your help, since it is a bug specific to my project I will investigate further on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically risking invalidating your `image` object (as in not available) when you get to the callback handler as image loading is asynchronous and the function will (most likely) exit before the `onload` is called.

Try to do a little switch around such as this:

```
var imageLoader = function(x, y, src) {

    var image = new Image();

    function draw() {
        // use *this* here instead of image
        ctx.drawImage(this, x, y)
    };

    image.onload = draw;
    image.src = src;

    tooltip.icons.push(image);
};
```

Instead of the small hack here you could store the coordinates (and urls) in an array and iterate through that.